# SPI device access using SPIDEV

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi

I want to access an SPI device (an optical mouse device from Avago Tech) on an embedded Linux system using the SPIDEV driver. The device is connected to SPI0.

I enabled SPI and "User mode SPI device driver support" in menuconfig > "Device Drivers" > "SPI".

I added the code to the board.c file

```
static struct spi_board_info spidev_board_info[] {
    {
        .modalias = "spidev",
        .max_speed_hz = 1000000,
        .bus_num = 1,
        .chips_select = 0,
        .mode = SPI_MODE_3,
    },
    {
        .modalias = "spidev",
        .max_speed_hz = 1000000,
        .bus_num = 1,
        .chips_select = 1,
        .mode = SPI_MODE_3,
    },
};
spi_register_board_info(spidev_board_info, ARRAY_SIZE(spidev_board_info));
```

I tried both 500000 and 1000000 as max_speed_hz (1Mhz being the highest allowed by the sensor). SPI_MODE_3 is correct, checked on the datasheet. bus_num = 1 should correct as it refers to SPI0 (I also tried = 0 out of curiosity).

I checked the electrical connections and are all working.

The kernel compiles and the image starts correctly, but I cannot find any device in /sys/class/spidev/ (neither in /sys/bus/spi/...). No reference to SPI appears during system boot either.

Any idea on where the problem can be?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a spi master controller enabled (in your kernel) ? On what embedded system are you trying to achieve this, so that we can make sure the correct driver is enabled (and we also have to make sure that it gets initialized).

Comment: It's Atmel ARM processor AT91SAM9G25. SPI master is enabled (I checked and also the folder "/sys/class/spi_master" esists).

Comment: But if it's enabled but see nothing at boot regarding SPI, it may be that the "spi master" device is not enabled. What's the name of the board and its corresponding board file (in arch/arm/at91) ? If everything was inititalized correctly here, you should see some "Atmel SPI Controller ..." in your kernel boot.

Comment: The board file is "board-sam9x5ek.c" (as the name of the board)

Comment: The file is not mainline yet, but I have found the corresponding patch on the mailing-list. It's in this file that you have to add you spi devices, you can just append them into the ek_spi_devices[] table and then the at91_add_device_spi is already called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that with the Atmel boards, you are supposed to register the devices with the at91_add_device_spi function. It would then be:

```
at91_add_device_spi(spidev_board_info, ARRAY_SIZE(spidev_board_info));
```

At least you have to make sure that this function gets called by your board support file `board-sam9x5ek.c` so that the SPI master controller gets initialized. If this is done, your above proposed initialization is correct.

Comment: I did so and the devices appeared as spidevX.X. I'm now trying to use IOCTL as suggested in spidev.h but my program get stuck on callong IOCTL. Can it be that the real sensor is not "connected" (electrically, it is) and those devices are just there because I put the code in the BSP?

Comment: Definitely, the spidev driver is not going to check if the HW really answers. What we usutally do in drivers is reading a register with a Chip ID and check if the read value is what is expected.

Comment: Exactly, when I try to send any IOCTL (to read the WHOAMI register) it gets stuck. It doesn't even reach the read part, it stops at the write part (in which I send the register number). Can it be because of missing HW?